# Understanding how regularization penalizes higher order features

Tags: regression, regularization, tikhonov-regularization

I am trying to understand how exactly L2 or ridge regression penalize higher order polynomial features to make fitting curve smoother. I read [this](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/l1-l2-regularization-7f1b4fe948f2) article about regularization. I contemplated and I feel that I still dont get the whole concept clearly. Let me tell my understanding first below.

- Consider we have sample size of $n=2$.
- Number of parameters $m=5$, $\theta_0$ to $\theta_4$
- Hypothesis function $h_\theta(x_i)=\theta_0+\theta_1x_{i1}+\theta_2x_{i2}^2+\theta_3x_{i3}^3+\theta_4x_{i4}^4$,
  where $x_{ij}$ is $j$th feature of $i$th training instance.
- Loss function with L2 regularization applied is:
  $$L=\frac{1}{2n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n=2}(y_i-h_\theta(x_i))^2+\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{m=4}\theta_j^2 \right) \quad\quad\quad\text{...equation (0)} $$
  where $\lambda$ is regularization parameter (determines severity of regularization penalty) and $\sum_{j=1}^{m=4}\theta_j^2$ is actual regularization penalty.

**Q1.** I am not getting why adding  $\sum_{j=1}^{m=4}\theta_j^2$ reduces effect of bigger order features, say $x^3_{i3}$ and $x^3_{i4}$ in above loss function? Or is it that, the penalization does not occur in the loss function itself but when we apply gradient descent as explained below and asked in Q2?

If we want to consider gradient descent, then first we will calculate the partial derivatives as follows:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_0}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n=2}(y_i-h_\theta(x_i))$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_{j=1..m}}=\frac{1}{n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n=2}(y_i-h_\theta(x_i))x_{ij}+\lambda\theta_j\right)$

The rough sketch of gradient descent will be:

> $Repeat \{$
> $\theta_0=\theta_0-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n=2}(y_i-h_\theta(x_i))\quad\quad\quad\text{...equation (1)}$
> $\theta_{j=1..m}=\theta_j-\frac{\alpha}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n=2}(y_i-h_\theta(x_i))x_{ij}+\lambda\theta_j\right)\quad\quad\quad\text{...equation (2)}$
> $\}$

Equation (2) can be re written as:

$\theta_{j=1..m}=\theta_j(1-\alpha\frac{\lambda}{n})-\frac{\alpha}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n=2}(y_i-h_\theta(x_i))x_{ij}\right)$

**Q2.** Is it above $\theta_j(1-\alpha\frac{\lambda}{n})$ which is referred to when we say regularization penalizes weights?

**Q3.** If answer to Q2 is yes, then what about $\theta_3x_{i3}^3$ and $\theta_4x_{i4}^4$ terms thats still there un-penalized inside $h_\theta(x_i)$?

**Q4.** Also, equation (0) we add $\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{m=4}\theta_j^2$ for $j=1$ to $4$, not just for $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$. So how it penalises only higher order features and not lower order features like $x_{i1}$ and $x_{i2}$ etc? Can you show this mathematically with some equations?

(Also let me know if I made any mathematical mistake)

Comment: Is this regularization actually trying to penalize higher order terms or is it trying to penalize larger coefficients and as a side effect more coefficients (i.e. having higher-order terms)?

Comment: so as described it doesn't penalise the higher order terms. you need to first rescale each power term to unit variance. imagine your inputs are +/- 10. a small coefficient on    x^4 will still have a higher variance than a large coefficient on x^1

Comment: @Wayne AFAIK regularization is said to penalize coefficients such that it in result penalize higher order terms.